# Unable to read contents of Text File C++

Tags: c++, file-io, visual-studio-2005

I have the following code in Socket.cpp -

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include "CommandProcessor.h"

void main()
{
    CommandProcessor cp;
    cp.RetrieveTag();
    std::getchar();
}
```

And the function RetrieveTag() is as follows -

```
void CommandProcessor::RetrieveTag()
{
    std::ifstream file;
    std::string filename = "C:\Users\mraman\Desktop\input.txt";
    std::string str;
    std::string file_contents;
    file.open(filename.c_str());
    while (std::getline(file, str))
    {
        file_contents += str;
        file_contents.push_back('\n');
    }
    cout<<file_contents;
}
```

Though input.txt contains data, when I put a breakpoint and debug, it doesn't go into the while loop itself and hence doesn't display the file contents as output.

Comment: `"C:\Users\mraman\Desktop\input.txt";` should be `"C:\\Users\\mraman\\Desktop\\input.txt";` You need to escape the `\` in the string literal.

Comment: You might want to check first if the `open` succeeded. You can do this by: `if ( file ) { ... }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"C:\Users\mraman\Desktop\input.txt";` should be `"C:\\Users\\mraman\\Desktop\\input.txt";` You need to escape the `\` in the string literal.

Also, you might want to check the state of the `ifstream` by using the `operator!`.

```
if( file ) { .... }
```